# Why am I getting this error (Tailwind + Next.js)? HookwebpackError, CssSyntaxError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Been having this issue for a week now and haven't been able to find a solution, but I figured out some things to narrow down the issue. I'm attempting to run yarn build in my Next.js application but it fails with an error that I'll post below.

The program app compiles fine with `yarn dev` and all the styles work. I used the standard setup from the TW docs.

Could bad style names cause errors with building? For example `className="BadStyleName h-10 w-10"`

Error:

```
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: C:\Users\project\static\css\b0067dc6dc66c8dc.css:2251:12: Unknown word
    at makeWebpackError (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:47168:9)
    at C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:31056:12
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:141512:10), <anonymous>:34:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
-- inner error --
CssSyntaxError: C:\Users\project\static\css\b0067dc6dc66c8dc.css:2251:12: Unknown word
    at Input.error (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at ScssParser.unknownWord (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at ScssParser.other (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at ScssParser.parse (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at scssParse (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:335)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:122:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:33:12)
    at CssMinimizerPlugin.optimizeAsset (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\css-minimizer-plugin.js:43:12)
    at C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\css-minimizer-plugin.js:77:55
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
CssSyntaxError: C:\Users\project\static\css\b0067dc6dc66c8dc.css:2251:12: Unknown word
    at Input.error (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at ScssParser.unknownWord (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at ScssParser.other (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at ScssParser.parse (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at scssParse (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:335)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:122:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:33:12)
    at CssMinimizerPlugin.optimizeAsset (C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\css-minimizer-plugin.js:43:12)
    at C:\Users\project\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\css-minimizer-plugin.js:77:55
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)


> Build failed because of webpack errors
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

`tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  darkMode: true, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
            flex: {
                basis: '0 0 100%',
            },
            colors: {
                primary: { mint: "#18BCFF" },
                slate: {
                    50: "#f8fafc",
                    100: "#f1f5f9",
                    200: "#e5e5e5",
                    300: "#d4d4d4",
                    400: "#a3a3a3",
                    500: "#737373",
                    600: "#525252",
                    700: "#404040",
                    800: "#262626",
                    900: "#171717"
                }
            },
        }
        
  },

  plugins: [
        require('daisyui'),
        require('@tailwindcss/line-clamp'),
        require('tailwind-scrollbar'),
    ],
    variants: {
        scrollbar: ['rounded']
    }
}
```

`next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
    domains: ['firebasestorage.googleapis.com'],
  },
}
```

`_app.js`:

```js
import "../styles/globals.css"
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'
import Layout from "../components/layout/layout"
import "../firebase/clientApp"
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"
import MintBG from "../components/layout/mintBG"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
        <div className="text-white overflow-hidden">
            <AnimatedBG />
            <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
                <Layout>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Layout>    
            </SessionProvider>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

`postcss.config.js`

```js
console.log("Testing Postcss")

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

`package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "project",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.3.0",
    "daisyui": "^1.16.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "embla-carousel-react": "^6.0.2",
    "firebase": "^9.4.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "firebaseui": "^6.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "latest",
    "next-auth": "^4.0.0-beta.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "svg-react-loader": "^0.4.6",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "eslint": "8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "react-svg-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "tailwind-scrollbar": "^1.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.6"
  }
}
```

Notes:

- The `console.log()` from `postcss.config.js` edit: IS PRINTED
- `C:\Users\project\static\css\b0067dc6dc66c8dc` doesn't seem to resolve to a file when I alt+click it.
- The app will build fine when `"./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",` is removed from `content: []` in `tailwind.config.js`. `/components/` jsx won't receive any TW styling, but the jsx in `/pages/` work as expected.
- removing `plugins: []` & `variants: {}` doesn't fix it.
- `@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;` are imported in `globals.css`.

Comment: You didn't post the error.  Did you install autoprefixer and postcss and set up the postcss.config? The tailwind 3 next.js guide is incomplete - look at their v2 docs https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs#creating-your-project  the v3 example has the packages - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/4d4f3093019179b1928ec07c16f38882241c0375/examples/with-tailwindcss

Comment: My apologies. Let me edit that now. And yeah I believe I followed the docs and installed Autoprefixer and Postcss. I'll post the `postcss.config.js`

Comment: What exactly is `@tailwind#9647 base;` ? Shouldn't that be simply `@tailwind base;`? Same for components and utilities.

Comment: @brc-dd I'm not sure why they copied over like that. I'll edit it.

Comment: It looks like that there is a particular class in one of your `components` that is breaking the css. The error is occurring only on build because CssMinimizerPlugin runs only while generating production build. Try to find out that class.

Comment: @brc-dd Thank you! I'll take a look.

Answer (score 27):

Had the same problem today. Recheck all of your components styles. Check if you are passing dynamic value to the tailwind's custom className like `w-[${width}px]`. And change it to the inline react style like `style={{ width }}`. It causes the error during build time.

Comment: The issue ended up being inline comments at the end of my component. I have no idea why.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution @father! I had a dynamic class which caused the issue.

Comment: This answered it for me!

Comment: @Father you are a true life saver! Unbelievable I got this error from a commented out code, same as Yammel N

Comment: @Father You are a savior. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Don't we have any other solution apart from changing the class to style tag? Because I have used that at a lot of places in around more than 100 components changing that would be a nigtmare

Comment: This solved the same issue for me. There was a component that was using h-[${size}px] as a class name. I just got rid of the variable and it built ok.

Comment: It's weird that it accepts arbitrary dynamic values in the dev environment, but not during the build. :/ Also @mzparacha raises a fair concern, what if there are tons of components with this nature of styling? Please comment if anybody came up with a solution.

Comment: Why is dynamic class name not working? What is wrong with `w-[${width}px]`?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had a line in the block of a component like this:

```
function Foo({ givenListPaperWidth = 200 }) {
    // ...
    // The below line was commented
    // const listPaperWidth = `w-[${givenListPaperWidth}px]`;  (**)
    
    return "Foo component";
}
```

Even though "(**) line" was commented, it was causing build error.
After deleting the line, build was done successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible cause might be the semicolons in `tailwind.config` 
Remove the semicolons in css strings in `tailwind.config`

```
  boxShadow: {
      card: 'rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 8px 0px;',  // migth cause this error
  }

  boxShadow: {
      card: 'rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 8px 0px',  // Remove semi ;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the comments at the end of my file (not even inside the component) and the build command worked successfully. Sometimes code is just unbelievable.

Answer (score 1):

Guys the bug is super easy
What i had done is , i had added an ; in the tailwind.config file , on removing that, the build was successful

Ex :

```
tailwind.config.js 

Module.export ={
...
     Boxshadow :{
      lg:"12px 12px 12px 24px rgba(74,74,75,. 0.6";(this ; caused the build fail, after removing ; i was able to build production build )
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While my predecessors are correct in their asessment, the problem can sometimes be hard to spot.

In such a case one might try to use RegEx to look for any occurances of `\[[^]]*\$`, to try and spot variables in brackets, or search for className in general.

If your codebase is decently sized though that can get quite tricky anyway.

Build a Binary Search tree with your `tailwind.config.js`'s content array.

1. Include nothing by passing empty array and verify that your build runs again, meaning the problem is definitely in your codebase and not in your tailwind config.
2. Then include half of your codebase folders (Use `ls > folders.txt` and MultiCursor edit, to generate the imports quickly, if you have a shallow structure)

- If it works still: Include half of the remaining codebase
- If it doesnt work: Remove half of the included codebase

This will lead you to the specific file with minimal amount of builds.

Maybe there is better ways to debug this, if you are willing to put effort into debugging the webpack bundler, but the main error log of this particular error does not really help you to find the source of the problem sadly.

We only the that the problem lies in the scss parser of postcss, which makes sense, as that is what runs the tailwind build pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like everyone has a different variation of a problem that causes this exception. For me it was because I had a class in my globals.css file called `.aspect-ratio-4/3`. The use of the unescaped forward slash in the class name prevented compilation.

Here is how I changed the class name:

```
.aspect-ratio-4\\/3::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  padding-top: 75%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your build command with this one and give a try if it works or not,

```
"build": "rm -rf build && yarn cache clean && rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && yarn upgrade --latest && react-scripts build",
```

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this build problem by removing the plugins section from tailwind.config.js and moving it to the tailwind.css.

[image: git diff showing changes]