# How do I fix Tailwindcss unknown word error?

Tags: tailwind-css

When I try to run

```
$ tailwindcss build -i src/style.css -o public/style.css
```

it gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\pex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\peers\index.js:3211
          result = new CssSyntaxError(message, endLine === void 0 ? line : { line, column }, endLine === void 0 ? column : { line: endLine, column: endColumn }, this.css, this.file, opts.plugin);
                   ^

CssSyntaxError: D:\WebDev\tailwind-starter\src\style.css:1:1: Unknown word
    at Input.error (C:\Users\pex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\peers\index.js:3211:20)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\Users\pex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\peers\index.js:4738:26)
    at Parser.other (C:\Users\pex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\peers\index.js:4416:16)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\pex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\peers\index.js:4329:20)
    at parse (C:\Users\pex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\peers\index.js:4787:16)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\pex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\peers\index.js:4932:20)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\pex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\peers\index.js:5420:18)
    at C:\Users\pex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli.js:512:34 {
  reason: 'Unknown word',
  file: 'D:\\WebDev\\tailwind-starter\\src\\style.css',
  source: '��@\x00t\x00a\x00i\x00l\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00 \x00b\x00a\x00s\x00e\x00;\x00\r\x00\n' +
    '\x00@\x00t\x00a\x00i\x00l\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00 \x00c\x00o\x00m\x00p\x00o\x00n\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00s\x00;\x00\r\x00\n' +
    '\x00@\x00t\x00a\x00i\x00l\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00 \x00u\x00t\x00i\x00l\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00e\x00s\x00;\x00',
  line: 1,
  column: 1,
  endLine: 1,
  endColumn: 3,
  input: {
    line: 1,
    column: 1,
    endLine: 1,
    endColumn: 3,
    source: '��@\x00t\x00a\x00i\x00l\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00 \x00b\x00a\x00s\x00e\x00;\x00\r\x00\n' +
      '\x00@\x00t\x00a\x00i\x00l\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00 \x00c\x00o\x00m\x00p\x00o\x00n\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00s\x00;\x00\r\x00\n' +
      '\x00@\x00t\x00a\x00i\x00l\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00 \x00u\x00t\x00i\x00l\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00e\x00s\x00;\x00',
    url: 'file:///D:/WebDev/tailwind-starter/src/style.css',
    file: 'D:\\WebDev\\tailwind-starter\\src\\style.css'
  }
}
```

`src/styles.css` only contains

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Which tailwindcss version are you using?
For v2: `npx tailwindcss build -i src/style.css -o public/style.css`


If it's the latest (3) then follow this guide: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: @Shreshth I have followed the exact steps mentioned in the above link and it still gives me the same exact error which I mentioned in the original post.

Comment: Which tailwind version are you on? Can you share a github repo with a minimal reproduction of your issue? Also mention which OS with version you're on.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today, in my case I had a tailwind class that I incorrectly typed. I had: `class="w-[120 px]"` but it should've been `class="w-[120px]"`. That one space in one of my files was causing the error for me. I searched for "-[" in my vsCode to find all instances of arbitrary values in my project and finally found the culprit.

More on arbitrary values in tailwind [here](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support).

Also, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70466186/why-am-i-getting-this-error-tailwind-next-js-hookwebpackerror-csssyntaxerr?rq=1) helped me identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but I think I fixed it.
Please check if you have rgb values in tailwind.config.js.
if so, please change them into hex values.
From my experience tailwind has some troubles with rgb values.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).